# How to access localStorage of a firefox browser via Python?

Tags: python-3.x, local-storage, firefox-addon-sdk

following case.
I have a python script that opens a firefox browser on windows which has a firefox addon installed that writes logs into the local storage.

Before I close the browser via python I would like to read out the log information out of the local storage of the firefox.

So how can I access the localStorage in the firefox?

Help very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [PyXPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_bindings/PyXPCOM) and the [nsIDOMStorageManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsIDOMStorageManager) interface.

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/co-pyxp2/) to see how to use PyXPCOM.

You may start from this code (untested):

```
from xpcom import components

principal = (components.classes['@mozilla.org/scriptsecuritymanager;1']
    .getService(components.interfaces.nsIScriptSecurityManager)
    .getNoAppCodebasePrincipal(YOUR_URL))
dom_storage_manager = (components.classes['@mozilla.org/dom/localStorage-manager;1']
    .getService(components.interfaces.nsIDOMStorageManager))
local_storage = dom_storage_manager.getLocalStorageForPrincipal(principal, YOUR_URL)
```